# Apply EF core migrations one by one in code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I need to apply **Entity Framework Core migrations one by one in code**, i can call the `await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();` but it applies all the pending migrations in one block.

Is there an extension or other method to apply the migrations just one by one or selecting the name of the migration to apply?

Comment: Interesting, I have no answer for you, but would be really curious to hear what use case you have for needing this.

Comment: im applying data updates associated with each migration so i need each data update to be applied just after the migration

Comment: ah, right, ok, I could certainly see that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a [IMigrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrator) service with a `Migrate(string targetMigration)` method that receives the migration name, this method is used by the `Migrate()` extension.
From a DbContext instance it can be used as:

```
await dbContext.Database.GetInfrastructure().GetService<IMigrator>().MigrateAsync(targetMigrationName);
```

The pending migrations names can be queried by this extension:

```
var pending = dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations();
```

Comment: This is really useful for installer or updater tools that keep migration logic out of the main application.